# How to turn off optimization (-02) for apache modules built with APXS

Tags: apache

I'm trying to debug an apache module on RHEL and the optimization is getting in the way.  I tried deleting the '-O2' from `EXTRA_CFLAGS` in `apache_2.2.4/build/config_vars.mk, b`ut it didn't help. APXS is sufficiently complex (and my perl sufficiently poor) that I'm at a loss as to how to figure out how this flag is getting set.

Since odd things are happening, I'd like to turn optimization off for all of apache, not just the modules (yes, several) we add.

Anybody know how to turn off the optimizer? (so the debugger can work nicely).

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Marko's answer is close, but -g only provides debugging symbols and does not disable the optimizer (which is sometimes a [PITA](http://de.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pita) for debugging).

When I'm debugging my mod_epp module, I use:

Build apache with: ./configure --enable-maintainer-mode --prefix=/usr/local/apache2
Build/install the module with: /usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs -Wc,-O0 -c -i mod_epp.c

This leads to both -O2 and -O0 given to gcc, where -O0 wins.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your config_var.mk file again

the apxs program collates all these entries as CFLAGS

SHLTCFLAGS
CFLAGS
NOTEST_CPPFLAGS
EXTRA_CPPFLAGS
EXTRA_CFLAGS

Your -O2 must be in one of them.

Also, my config_var.mk is in /usr/lib/httpd/build/config_vars.mk on a RHEL5 machine i know

Answer (score 0):

```
mod_auth_foo.c:
        ${APXS} "-Wc,${AM_CFLAGS} ${DEFAULT_INCLUDES} ${CFLAGS}" -c mod_auth_foo.c ${AM_LDFLAGS} ${mod_auth_foo_LDFLAGS} ${mod_auth_foo_LIBADD}
```

is what I use in `Makefile.am` for an apache module, and this does properly propagate `-O0 -ggdb3` that I set via `configure CFLAGS="-O0 -ggdb3"`. The resulting make output would be

`/usr/lib64/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -prefer-pic -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -fPIC -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -DLDAP_DEPRECATED  -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -Wall -Waggregate-return   -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls  -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Winline -Wformat=2 -pipe  -I.. -I.. -O0 -ggdb3  -c -o mod_auth_foo.lo mod_auth_foo.c && touch mod_auth_foo.slo`, which looks about right.

No modification of Apache files was required.

Answer (score -3):

It should be enough for debugging if you add '-Wc,-g' parameter.